# Excel VBA Runtime Error 1004 ActiveSheet.ListObject.Range.Autofilter

Tags: excel, runtime-error, autofilter, vba

I have the following VBA Script do different things, like refreshing Information. I also wrote a line to Filter the tables, but it gives me the Runtime Error 1004.

Sorry if my english is bad. I'm no native speaker

```
Sub sync_and_sort()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("Start").Range("sync").Copy
Dim column As Integer, first As Boolean
column = 11
first = True

For Each wks In Worksheets
    For Each lio In wks.ListObjects
        Sheets(wks.Name).Range(lio.Name).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
        Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        Dim helper As String
        helper = lio.Name + "[tatsächliches Enddatum]"
        Sheets(wks.Name).ListObjects(lio.Name).Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Sheets(wks.Name).ListObjects(lio.Name).Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Sheets(wks.Name).Range(helper) _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
            , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
        With Sheets(wks.Name).ListObjects(lio.Name). _
            Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
        Sheets(wks.Name).Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(lio.Name).Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, _
            Criterial:="WAHR"
        Sheets(wks.Name).Range("A1").Select
    Next lio
    If first Then
        first = False
    Else
        Sheets(wks.Name).Columns(column).Hidden = False
        column = column + 1
    End If
Next wks
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, The spelling of `Criterial` in `Criterial:="WAHR"` is wrong. It should be `Criteria1:="WAHR"`. Notice the `1`? :)

Try this (**Tried and Tested**)

`ActiveSheet.ListObjects(lio.Name).Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="WAHR"`